# Не приходят IPN уведомления laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

у меня такой вопрос.
Еще около двух лет назад я пытался поставить Payeer на Laravel, но безуспешно. Столкнулся с проблемой на мой настроенные роут попросту не приходит IPN нотификация. Вышел из положения создав отдельный php файл в директории паблик, но это костыли.

Сейчас работаю уже с другой системой, PrimePayeer, опыта стало больше, но ситуация аналогичная, пытаюсь разобраться и нигде не могу найти решения.
На отдельный файл в директории /public нотификация сразу приходит.
А на функцию по следующим настройкам - нет

Функции:

```
public function success() {
    Storage::put('success.txt', 'no ip check');
    return view('payment.success');
}

public function fail() {
    return view('payment.fail');
}

public function status(Request $request) {
    Storage::put('notok.txt', 'no ip check');
    try {
        $secret = env('PRIMEPAYER_SECRET');

        Storage::put('ok.txt', 'no ip check');

        if (!in_array(request()->ip(), ['109.120.152.109', '145.239.84.249', true])) {
            exit();
        }

        Storage::put('user.txt', 'user_id: '.$request->uv_user);

        $sign = $request->sign;
        unset($request->sign);

        $data = $request->all();

        ksort($data,SORT_STRING);
        $signi = hash('sha256', implode(':', $data).':'.$secret);

        if($signi !== $sign) {
            Storage::put('log.txt', $signi.'\n\n'.$sign.'\n'.'Incorrect Sign');
        }

        $user = User::findOrFail($request->uv_user);
        $user->balance += $request->amount;
        $user->save();

        return response()->setStatusCode(200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Storage::put('errors.txt', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('/success', 'HomeController@success');
Route::post('/fail', 'HomeController@fail');
Route::post('/status', 'HomeController@status');
```

VerifyCSRF Middleware:

```
VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/success',
        '/fail',
        '/status'
    ];
    }
```

Касательно файликов в функции статус. Ни один так и не создался.
Что говорит о том что либо нотификация получила код 500, либо еще какой то статус код, который даже не дает выполниться элементарным функциям.

Очень хочется наконец-то разобрать IPN, ибо платежки больная тема.
Кто сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста как решить :)

Comment: А логи смотреть?

Comment: Если у вас не вызывается роут, это означает что либо вы таблицы роутинга неправильно настроили, либо обозначили там неправильный метод (POST, PUT). Смотрите логи как уже сказали выше.

Comment: @ArchDemon смотрел логи, там пусто. в 21:00 у меня было пару ошибок, связанных с миграцией, делал платежку вплоть до полуночи, в логах ничего не было